# Show Ant Scala compiler error with Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle

When running Scala compiling with Gradle on Jenkins we use the **scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = true**. Sometimes we also get compiler errors, delivered this way:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':application:compileScala'.
>   Compilation failed because of an internal compiler error; see the error output for details.

Unfortunately there is no error output. Even with **--stacktrace**

Anyone know any tweaks on how to tell Ant, through Gradle, to show the compiler error?

Comment: Sidenote: I could run with **--info** and the compiler error would show. But then the build will be a bit too verbose.

Comment: Update: See my answer on not using ScalaOptions.fork = true

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**
for some reason, the code snippet below doesn't really do the trick (I'll leave it in for future reference). However, this one does:
`compileScala.logging.level = LogLevel.DEBUG`

---

Try adding this to your build.gradle file:
`compileScala { // or: tasks.withType(ScalaCompile)
          logging.setLevel LogLevel.ERROR
}`

For more of an explanation the Gradle logging system, check out the [logging chapter in the Gradle user guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this didn't seem to do the trick. Looked pretty promising. Have you tested it @r02 ?

Comment: How odd, it does seem to work for me (using Gradle not through Jenkins). I'll try digging around, maybe I used additional tricks to get it to work. For the record, I've tested it on Gradle 2.0 and 2.3.

Comment: Don't bother @r02, I found the reason. Combining *fork* with *useAnt* is the culprit. Did a gradle init --type=scala-library and got to the bottom of it. I guess it might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept this as an answer, rather an heads up for those entering this issue laterwise. I'm too blame, as I gave too little information in the first place. Anyways, the culprit is using **fork** and **Ant** together like this:

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.fork = true
    scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = true
}
```

Remove the fork and the compiler error will light up like as if you were using Zinc. (we use Zinc locally and Ant on Jenkins)